# Set of random numbers between x and y, needs to be unique, using Kotlin

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

in Kotlin, I'm trying to, for example, get 5 numbers into an Array, List or ArrayList, the 5 numbers to come from 6 to 30. Been looking online and I ended up getting the following to work, however it isn't picking unique numbers for the list, so it could pick something like 6,6,20,24,24.

`val cardNumbersCol1 = (1..5).map { (6..30).random() }`

Is there a better way to do this?

I'm still learning as I go.

Thanks

Comment: Hey, I added one-liner option to my answer also. Can you check it out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can populate set with manual checking items:

```
var cardNumbersCol1 = mutableSetOf<Int>()
while (cardNumbersCol1.size < 5) {
  val item = (6..30).random()
  cardNumbersCol1.add(item)
}
```

Comment: absolutely brilliant, thank you so much. Makes so much sense when you see the answer

Answer (score 2):

**Option 1:** You can create `Set` because set cannot have duplicate elements by definition. Therefore, you won't need to worry about duplicate numbers:

```
val cardNumbersCol1 = mutableSetOf<Int>()

while (cardNumbersCol1.size != 5) {
    cardNumbersCol1.add(Random.nextInt(6, 30))
}
```

**Option 2:** You can generate range from 6 to 30 use `shuffled()` function to shuffle the list. Finally, you can take first 5 items from the list and they'll be unique also:

```
val cardNumbersCol1 = (6..30).shuffled().take(5).toSet()
```

Comment: the 1 liner is perfect and will come in handy, thank you

Answer (score 2):

Another approach is to use a sequence generator to produce a sequence of random Ints, and then filter by distinct and take the first few that you want:

```
fun randomGenerator(from: Int, 
                    until: Int, 
                    random: Random = Random.Default): Sequence<Int> = sequence {
    while(true) {
        yield(random.nextInt(from, until))
    }
}

fun main() {
    val someRandomInts: Set<Int> =
        randomGenerator(6, 30)
            .distinct()
            .take(5)
            .toSet()
    println(someRandomInts)
}
```

Or, you can define an extension function on `IntRange` to make this a bit prettier:

```
fun IntRange.randomSequence(random: Random = Random.Default): Sequence<Int> = sequence {
    while(true) {
        yield(this@randomSequence.random(random))
    }
}
```

And to use:

```
val someRandomInts: Set<Int> =
    (6..30).randomSequence().distinct().take(5).toSet()
```